# Sum and Mean of selected column in Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have below mentioned dataframe:

```
TYPE  Type1  Con1   Type2  Con2
A     10     5      15     2
B     NA     NA     10     3
C     20     10     NA     NA
D     5      5      15     3
```

I want to sume column 2&4 and mean of column 3&5, I have tried this `New_DF<-rbind(DF[-1],c(colSums(DF[,c(2,4)],colMeans(DF[,c(3,5)]))))` but it couldn't work.

Desired output:

```
TYPE    Type1  Con1   Type2  Con2
A       10     5      15     2
B       NA     NA     10     3
C       20     10     NA     NA
D       5      5      15     3
Total   35     5      40     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't consider the Nas:
here is my snap solution to your problem:
1- consider your data frame as follows:

```
dff <- data.frame(a1=c(1,NA,2,NA), a2=c(NA,2,2,2),b1=c(1,NA,2,NA), b2=c(NA,2,2,2) )
```

2- make to vectors, one for sums, and one for means:

```
sum_vector <- colSums(dff[,c(1,3)], na.rm = TRUE)
mean_vector <- colSums(dff[,c(2,4)], na.rm = TRUE)/nrow(dff)
```

3- make a vector as the last row:

```
last_row <- vector()
last_row[1] <- "TOTAL_ROW"
last_row[c(2,4)] <- sum_vector
last_row[c(3,5)] <- mean_vector
```

4-add the vectors to the main data frame as a new row

```
new_dff <- rbind(dff, c(last_row))
```

Comment: this error is coming `Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied` and How to Add `Total` Word in `new_dff`.

Comment: To sum and mean multiple i have used your code like this: `sum_vector <- colSums(DF[,c(2,3,6,7)], na.rm = TRUE)
mean_vector <- colSums(DF[,c(4,5,8,9)], na.rm = TRUE)/nrow(DF)
new_dff <- rbind(DF, c("Total", sum_vector, mean_vector))` but it gives me uneven columns in `new_dff`.

Comment: Updated Again, hope you have no problems anymore

Answer (score 1):

E.g. this way

```
df <- data.frame(Type  = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 Type1 = c(10, NA, 20, 5),
                 Con1  = c(5, NA, 10, 5),
                 Type2 = c(15, 10, NA, 15),
                 Con2  = c(2, 3, NA, 3), stringsAsFactors = F)

rbind(df, c("Total", colSums(df[, 2:5], na.rm = TRUE) / rep(c(1, nrow(df)), 2)))

   Type Type1 Con1 Type2 Con2
1     A    10    5    15    2
2     B  <NA> <NA>    10    3
3     C    20   10  <NA> <NA>
4     D     5    5    15    3
5 Total    35    5    40    2
```

Comment: How to do it if i want to sum first two column and than mean to next 2 column and than again repeat the same process.

Comment: Then you say `rep(c(1, nrow(df)), each = 2)` :)

Comment: This error is coming `Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`.

Comment: It's giving me sum of those values of which i want mean.

Comment: Then just reverse the 1, nrow(df) to nrow(df), 1.

Answer (score 0):

First, replace `NA` with 0.

```
dat2 <- dat
dat2[is.na(dat2)] <- 0
```

After that, use `sapply` to apply sum or mean to different column based on column names.

```
result <-  sapply(names(dat2[, -1]), function(x){
  if (grepl("Type", x)){
    return(sum(dat2[, -1][[x]]))
  } else if (grepl("Con", x)){
    return(mean(dat2[, -1][[x]]))
  }
})
```

And then merge the results.

```
dat3 <- data.frame(t(result))
dat3$TYPE <- "Total"

dat4 <- rbind(dat, dat3)
dat4
#    TYPE Type1 Con1 Type2 Con2
# 1     A    10    5    15    2
# 2     B    NA   NA    10    3
# 3     C    20   10    NA   NA
# 4     D     5    5    15    3
# 5 Total    35    5    40    2
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "TYPE  Type1  Con1   Type2  Con2
A     10     5      15     2
                  B     NA     NA     10     3
                  C     20     10     NA     NA
                  D     5      5      15     3",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```